# Bringing Active Directory Users using JNDI in multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, powershell, active-directory, jndi

I have designed an application which brings the users from the active directory to an MySQL database, and shows them on GUI. It also brings the groups of which a user is a member of.

So, my program works this way:

```
for(String domain : allConfiguredADomains)  {
    LdapContext domainCtx = getDomainCtx(domain);

    // Bring all users from this domain and store them in DB
    getAllUsersForDomain(domain, domainCtx);

    // Bring all the groups for every user
    getAllGroupsForUsersInTheDomain(domain, domainCtx)
}

void getAllUsersForDomain(String domain, LdapContext domainCtx) {
    String filter = "(objectClass=User)"

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = domainCtx.search(domain, filter, ..);
    while(result.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) result.nextElement();

        // Process and store in database
        storeUserInDatabase(searchResult);
    }
}

void getAllGroupsForUsersInTheDomain(String domain, LdapContext domainCtx)  {

    List<String> userDistinguishedNames = getAllUsersFromDatabase("distinguishedName");

    for(String userDn : userDistinguishedNames) {
        String filter = "(&(objectClass=Group)(distinguishedName=" + userDn + "))";

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> result = domainCtx.search(domain, filter, ..);

        List<String> allGroupsOfUser = new List<String>();
        while(result.hasMoreElements()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) result.nextElement();

            String groupDistinguishedName = searchResult.getAttributes().get("distinguishedName").get();
            allGroupsOfUser.add(groupDistinguishedName);
        }

        // Store them in database
        storeAllGroupsOfUserInDatabase(userDn, allGroupsOfUser);
    }
}
```

This application, however, takes lot of time, when there are too many users in the active directory. So, I decided to implement parallelism (using Threading). I divided this using search filter on `distinguishedName` of a user.

```
String filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(distinguishedName=a*"))";
```

and so on.. in each thread while fetching users.

- I got better performance, but still not so good. Can someone suggest
  a better way ?
- Also, I don't have an idea how can I introduce
  parallelism while fetching groups ?
- If someone has any suggestions to do this better with powershell or C#, please suggest, I am open to technology.

**Please note:** reading user attribute `memberOf` does not provide all groups, hence I am fetching groups separately.

Comment: Parallelism doesn't necessarily buy you very much. The disk isn't multi-threaded, or the network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Active Directory expert - just wanted to share some thoughts.

1. Threading by alphabet letter allows a maximum of 26 threads.  Have you considered creating search threads by some other attributes, group membership etc?  This might let you create more threads.
2. Review the Active Directory docs to see whether there is a way to improve search performance (for example, with a database we could create an index).